# Is it a good practice to do reverse navigation for model objects in a django template?

Tags: django, model, navigation

I am building a small learning management system. It has courses, activities for courses and activity responses for activities. The relationships between these objects is as shown below.

In a view I want to list in tabular form all activities for a course and all responses received for that activity. If I gave only the course object to my template then it would have to do reverse navigation from course to activities and subsequently from each activity to the ActivityResponse.

My question is what is the right way to navigate such a relationship? Is reverse navigation possible / advisable from templates, or should I pass appropriate dicts from the view to the template, so it can simply iterate over all the objects and display data.

```
class Course(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    contents = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()


class Activity(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    placement = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    contents = models.TextField()


class ActivityResponse(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity)
    when = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    contents = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep all knowledge about the structure of your model graph in your views. Templates should only be for formatting. The reason is that templates are fiddly to adapt to change - you will hate yourself if you tweak your models, then have to change all of your templates.

Comment: Yes I agree. I too was thinking along those lines. BTW, just for my understanding, is it possible to do reverse navigation (relationships) of model objects in a template ?